# Does SDL offer a free developer download?

Tags: documentation

I would like to learn a bit about Tridion by experimenting with it.

Does SDL offer a free download for learning/experimentation use? I know there are webinars I can look at and documents I can read, but I prefer learning by doing...

Comment: Adding my remark about the quality standards apparently improved the quality of this question... Weird.

Comment: Guessing here, but most likely this is a Stack Exchange feature which identified that your question contained very few words which is likely to be a bad question (one without much detail).

Comment: -1 for not doing the research as similar question is available on Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003091/sdl-tridion-license

Comment: +1 because in spite of it being on SO, this is a question that ought to be on this site. Well maybe it should be a faq, but I'm not sorry to see it here.

Comment: @PankajGaur I did do research, but used the wrong keywords. I was looking for "tridion download"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems a ever-present question. From [SDL Tridion World](http://www.sdltridionworld.com) if you have a [valid account](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/about/access/index.aspx) you can download the software. But unfortunately, if things have not changed, you can only obtain a Tridion license if one of the following situations apply to you:

- SDL employee
- [SDL Tridion partner](http://www.sdl.com/community/partner/partner-programs/tridion-partners/)
- SDL Tridion customer
- [SDL Tridion MVP](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/mvp_award/index.aspx)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691078/can-i-get-sdl-tridion-virtual-machine-for-my-own-purpose-without-license-cost) you will find more information.

Comment: Maybe worth adding to the FAQs.

Comment: @DanielGLB: to prevent "can you provide a link?" comments I would suggest not mentioning the sdltridionworld site. That site happens to link to the partner and customer extranets, where people falling in your second and third bullet can download the software.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this is very short: No.

If you want a license for SDL Tridion you have to purchase it by contacting SDL sales.

Comment: Why? I'm often involved in software selection projects. My advise usually is to pick software for which it's easy to find developers. SDL creates a very high barrier to entry for new developers to pick up the knowledge required. This will result in less developers, and higher prices. Not a desireable situation for companies using Tridion.

Comment: It is not up to me to answer the why, that is just what SDL management decided, I'm just the messenger.